# Deep learning in Python - Why i'm getting just epoch 1/10 after running the following code?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

What is the error here

```
model =tf.keras.Sequential{[
tf.keras.layers(input_shape=(28,28,1)),
MaxPooling2D(pool_size=2),
Dropout(0.2),
train_images.reshape(train_images.shape[0],28,28,1),

tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),

tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation='softmax')])

model.compile(optimizer='Adam',loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True),metrics=['accuracy'])
```

This is the error I'm getting

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-bdb2a68d9b5f> in <module>
      1 model = tf.keras.Sequential([
      2 
----> 3 tf.keras.layers(input_shape=(28,28,1)),
      4 MaxPooling2D(pool_size=2),
      5 Dropout(0.2),

TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

Comment: `tf.keras.layers` is a module which implements layers. you have to choose a layer for your input

Comment: how to choose a layer

Comment: like you did for mostly all other layers

Comment: or how's the code supposed to be

Comment: can you show the code

Comment: just look at your code: `tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu')`  here you used a dense layer. here `tf.keras.layers(input_shape=(28,28,1))` you didnt used any layer, just tried to call a module. you probably want to use a conv layer

Comment: you mean .Conv2D?

Comment: tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(input_shape=(28,28,1)) like this?

Comment: it depends on your input data, but generally yes

Comment: after editing im getting - TypeError: __init__() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'filters' and 'kernel_size'

Comment: It seems you are working with MNIST data, as @luigigi pointed you can use a dense layer like you have used later in the model or you can use a conv2D layer. Basically replace `tf.keras.layers(input_shape=(28,28,1))` with `tf.keras.layers.Dense(128,activation='relu',input_shape=(28,28,1))`

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
model =tf.keras.Sequential([
tf.keras.layers.Dense(128,activation='relu',input_shape=(28,28,1)),
MaxPooling2D(2),
Dropout(0.2),
train_images.reshape(train_images.shape[0],28,28,1),
tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),
tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation='softmax')])

model.compile(optimizer='Adam',loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True),metrics=['accuracy'])
```

Comment: TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-27-cb3c7814a87e> in <module>
      6 tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
      7 tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),
----> 8 tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation='softmax')])
      9 
     10 model.compile(optimizer='Adam',loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True),metrics=['accuracy'])

Comment: ypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)

Comment: im also getting this - TypeError: The added layer must be an instance of class Layer.

Comment: please help if you know

Comment: I need a full [minimum_working_example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) with the error. I am not able to get it completely.

Comment: okay what do you do when there's an error called added layer must be an instance of class layer

Comment: This isn't working because a tf.keras layer is getting added to a keras Model. So I need to see a minimum working example. Which line exactly is causing this problem can you show that atleast.

Comment: this one - tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation='softmax')])

Comment: Are you using the code i provided I see you misplaced a round bracket with curly bracket in the first line : use `model =tf.keras.Sequential([` in place of `model =tf.keras.Sequential{[`

Comment: curly bracket is not allowed in kaggle nb instead  round we have to use

Comment: I am unable to get you completely. Try to follow this link : [link](https://github.com/Akhilesh64/Tensorflow/blob/master/Fashion%20MNIST/Fashion_MNIST.ipynb)